# Having issues downloading gulp

Tags: javascript, gulp

Here is what the terminal output looks like:

```
Kayas-MacBook-Pro:~ pineapplelaptop$ npm install --global gulp-cli
npm WARN deprecated urix@0.1.0: Please see https://github.com/lydell/urix#deprecated
npm WARN deprecated resolve-url@0.2.1: https://github.com/lydell/resolve-url#deprecated
npm ERR! code EEXIST
npm ERR! syscall symlink
npm ERR! path ../lib/node_modules/gulp-cli/bin/gulp.js
npm ERR! dest /usr/local/bin/gulp
npm ERR! errno -17
npm ERR! EEXIST: file already exists, symlink '../lib/node_modules/gulp-cli/bin/gulp.js' -> '/usr/local/bin/gulp'
npm ERR! File exists: /usr/local/bin/gulp
npm ERR! Remove the existing file and try again, or run npm
npm ERR! with --force to overwrite files recklessly.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /Users/pineapplelaptop/.npm/_logs/2020-04-06T16_00_35_220Z-debug.log
Kayas-MacBook-Pro:~ pineapplelaptop$
```

Has anyone else faced this issue?

Comment: Can you please add your npm and node versions.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried doing what it says?

```
npm ERR! Remove the existing file and try again, or run npm
npm ERR! with --force to overwrite files recklessly.
```

Also, try the command `npm config list` to see what all configs are present in npm.

Comment: Yeah, I had done it multiple times and it didn't seem like it was doing anything. But I ended up getting gulp to download shortly after by just doing more research. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I resolved in ubuntu, reinstall node

```
sudo apt-get remove nodejs

sudo apt-get install nodejs

sudo npm install --global gulp-cli
```

Answer (score 0):

I used the below command for windows which worked.

npm config set strict-ssl false